# converting two column result to one column result in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Test]  @locid int as  begin
    declare @Mns decimal , @dec decimal
    select @dec= AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ))  FROM Transaction_tbl t WHERE Locid=@locid;
    select @Mns=@dec%60;


select HH=convert(decimal(10) ,@dec/60), mm=@Mns;
end
```

My out put is:
HH  |   mm
    | 
29      6  my out put is returning in two column,,i want to get out put in one column,
My expected out put like this:
HH:mm
29:6 how i can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select HH=convert(varchar(10),(convert(decimal(10) ,@dec/60)))+':' +convert(varchar,@Mns)
```